# can i access old property with new property in javascript or vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i create new property name styleTitle and i want get styleTitle = title + styleTitle. i tried in vue js it show result undefineObject

```
const person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  title: "Style",
  styleTitle: this.title + "Object",
  eyeColor: "blue"
};
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask the question for both JS and Vue. The principle is the same but the actual solution depends on your case. It would be different for reactive Vue object. Consider reasking with your exact case if the dupe question doesn't solve the problem

Comment: i try to use const person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  title: "Style",
  styleTitle: funtion(){
         this.title + "Object"}
  eyeColor: "blue"
}; 
in vue js but out put : (funtion(){this.title + "Object"}) is text ?

Comment: It would be done *in JS* the way that the answer suggested, but in Vue it usually isn't because this doesn't work with reactivity

Comment: thank you @EstusFlask i'll try more .

Comment: Hello @EstusFlask can u help show me some example about this [link](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#using-javascript-expressions) `<div :id="`list-${id}`"></div>`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you have a specific case in mind, consider reasking the question that reflects your problem, it needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

If a property of an object is based on another property, consider using [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```js
const person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  title: "Style",
  eyeColor: "blue",
  get styleTitle() {
    return this.title + "Object"
  },
};

console.log(person.styleTitle);
```

Comment: what get keyword meaning ?

Comment: I attached the link to [`get` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). It should work for all major browsers, unless the object itself got serialized.